# Share a paragraph (or part of a text) on facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just saw a new feature for sharing a part of text on facebook. c.f. http://www.metrolyrics.com/someone-like-you-lyrics-adele.html

This should be done by javascript and probably with aid of jQuery. Is there a developed plugin for this purpose? What is the pathway to develop this idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Facebook Javascript SDK to call the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).  You put the text you want, in their case the lyrics, in the caption and description properties of the feed dialog.